# Rails 3.1 Active Record associations possibly with nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a question regarding a simple app I am developing in Rails 3.1, but I am not sure of how to define the associations and am looking for advice on the best way to achieve the following.

I have tapes, each tape contains a barcode.

I have boxes, each box has a name

What i need to track is the act of associating the two  , each day up to 24 tapes will be placed into a Box, so i need a way of creating a new association for existing boxes and existing tapes on a form, and ideally track some extra information.

The tapes are on a 5 week cycle, so after 5 weeks a tape will ( possibly ) be associated with a new box.

I am not sure how to model the associations, any help or input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to track which box it used to belong to? If not, this is a simple belongs_to/has_many association.

```
class Tape
  belongs_to :box
end
class Box
  has_many :tapes
end
```

If you need to track past boxes, then you'll need a join-model:

```
class WhateverYouWant
   belongs_to :box
   belongs_to :tape
end
```

and change the box/tape associations to use ":through"

Comment: Thanks for this, its defiantly the bottom one, on what model would I create the form to do the association, Do you know of any tutorials on creating a NEW record in the "WhateverYouWant" Model but using existing records from the other two models? I basicly envisage a form with a text input for the Box name and then 24 text box's for the barcodes but I am not sure if this needs some extra work in the controller or if the accepts_nested_attributes would take care of this for me?

Comment: Is it possible to create a form on the join model that would pull from the Tape and Box models? I have added acceps_nested_attributes_for :tapes but I am not sure how to get the ID's of the tapes that already exist

Comment: Hi, sorry - I've been away. Join models are quite a common Rails pattern. You can google for it and find heaps of tutorials. No idea of a good one, but if you have the "web development with rails" book you'll have something in there on it. Otherwise google gives me: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-models.htm
(scroll down for it).